# Reverse a string for loop. Help me to understand the code

Tags: javascript, arrays

Task: Reverse and array,
My Solution:

```
function printReverse(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
   }
}
printReverse([1,2,3,4]);
```

My solution is correct but I don't understand why do we have to set the conditon to be `i >= 0` why can't we set it to be `i === 0`

Comment: It's not correct. Have you noticed that it always starts off with `undefined`? An array that has 4 elements in it is indexed by numbers 0 through 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement defines when the loop will continue executing, not when it will stop.

So, if you made the statement `i === 0`, the loop would never execute, because in the first iteration, the value of `i` would be the length of the array (which is only 0 when the array is empty).

As an aside, I believe your code actually has a small bug.  `i` should start being set to `arr.length - 1;`; as is, in the first iteration of the loop, it is printing out 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

> condition
>   An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. **If this expression evaluates to true**, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

The statement is only executed only if the condition is true so if you'd use `i === 0` the content of your for would never be executed

Answer (score -1):

in first iterate the length is 4 and in for condition you check is `0 === 4` and its `false` so loop is end , but when you check `4 >= 0` it's return true.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function printReverse(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
   }
}
printReverse([1,2,3,4]);
```

You can't set `i = 0` because it will cause the initial value of `i` to be zero therefore causing the loop to start from `0` which would be the first element in an array.

The reason why you have to set `i = arr.length - 1` is so it can start counting from the last item in the array.
`i--` tells the loop to continuously decrement the value of `i` until the condition `i >= 0` is met.

I set `i = arr.length - 1` i.e. length of the array minus one, so that it starts it count at exactly the last element in the array. In your case where you had to use `i = arr.length`, the first value of `i` will be `undefined`.

`i >= 0`, simply tells the loop to continue running until `i` is neither greater than zero nor equal to zero. At this point, the loop terminates.

Answer (score -1):

The condition in the for loop is the condition that keeps repeating the loop. Setting it to `i === 0` wouldn't even enter the cycle, if your array length is not 0.